# Java - Creating a pdf file for JAX-RS REST but response contains empty file

Tags: java, rest, pdf

I am generating a pdf file with pdfbox and try to return it from Jersey (jax-rs) REST API. 
The problem is that received pdf file is empty. If I save the file in server the file correct.
Maybe the problem is in stream or Response handling.

I have tried to solve this quite some time now and would like to get it finally working.

This is the code which I try use.

```
@GET
@Path("/generateReport/{name}/{id}")
@Produces("application/pdf")
public Response generateReport(@PathParam("name") String name) {

    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    PDFont courierBoldFont = PDType1Font.COURIER_BOLD;
    int fontSize = 12;

    PDPageContentStream contentStream;
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        document.addPage(page);
        contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setFont(courierBoldFont, fontSize);
        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(150, 750);
        contentStream.showText("Hello " + name);
        contentStream.endText();
        contentStream.close();
        document.save(output);
        document.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Response.ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.ok(output.toByteArray());
    responseBuilder.type("application/pdf");
    responseBuilder.header("Content-Disposition", "filename=test.pdf");
    return responseBuilder.build();
}
```

As mentioned above if I save a document as a file instead of stream then created pdf is correct with code below.

```
document.save("/Users/solmar/Dev/temp/" + name + ".pdf");
```